# MySQL JOIN when inserting data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have two tables: `images` and `servers`. Here's the schema relating to those two tables:

`id, name, uploaded, views, server_id`

`id, name, description, drive_space, enabled`

On the `images` table, `server_id` is a foreign key to the `id` field in the `servers` table. Pretty simple stuff. Many images belong to one server.

When I insert an image, it *has* to have a key pointing to the server the image is hosted on. When I insert the row, I'm given the name of the server (not its id) so I can't just insert it. I can achieve what I want with two queries (one to get the server ID and another to insert the image into the database) but idealy I want it done in one query with a JOIN as it's best practice.

I'm almost clueless with JOINS when it comes to SELECT statements and even more so with an INSERT. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Just Click [HERE](http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-set-up-foreign-key-constraint-in.html) It will help you to Understand the Foreign Key Concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a join. Just use a INSERT ... SELECT ...:

```
INSERT INTO images
(name, uploaded, views, server_id)
SELECT 'imagename', CURTIME(), 0, id
FROM servers
WHERE name = 'servername'
```

Comment: +1. This is the way to go. But, if we don't have a guarantee of uniqueness of the `servers.name` column, we can add a `LIMIT 1` to avoid the insert adding more than 1 row. Also, there's a possibility that the servername value will not be found, so the app would need to check that `rows_affected > 0`, and handle the condition when it isn't, rather than assuming a row was successfully inserted.